# Oversampling the dataset with pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, oversampling

I'm quite new to PyTorch and python. and I have a binary classification problem where one class have more samples than the other, so I decided to oversample the class that has less number of samples by doing **more** augmentation on it, so for example I would generate 7 images out of one sample for one class, while for the other class I would generate 3 images out of one sample. I'm using imguag for augmentation with PyTorch, so I'm not sure which is better, to augment my dataset first, then passing it to torch.utils.data.Dataset class, or reading the data and augmenting it inside **init** function of Dataset class.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is another way to deal with the unbalanced data, `nn.BCELoss` is a common choice for the binary classification problem, you can set a `pos_weight` to balance positive and negative samples. If you do so, you can apply same augmentation to all samples. Here is the code:

```
# defines the augmentation
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomRotation(20),
                            transforms.Resize((32, 32)),
                            transforms.ToTensor(),
                            transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
# initializes the data set
dataset = Dataset(train_data_path, transforms=transform)
# defines the loss function
criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss(torch.tensor([10.]))
```

Comment: I guess it's different than oversampling, I wish to try oversampling first, then maybe I would try changing the weight.